# package Vagrant/Chef build with ALL dependancies

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Current setup:

I have a project that builds with Vagrant/Chef (bunch of other tools, docker, bundler etc in play as well but this is the focus) Target is only Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

1) Vagrant sets up a ubuntu VM runs Chef with Berkshelf and all the other Ruby build goodies.

2) Chef runs through all the cookbooks:

- presumably download any missing dependencies via aptitude, install packages via dpkg
- pull/build source from git repos
- initialize databases, probably set permissions and create files etc

There are some tools such as https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby that claim to effectively "freeze" a ruby application so you can ship it with an interpreter and all the dependencies/gems. This would be fine for a static application if not the last bit: running through cookbooks is actually an important step to deploying the application.

The deploy target will have no or limited bandwidth, is it possible to package a Chef build to locally contain all dependencies so that no remote download is necessary?

My idea so far is to run a clean build and make a copy of the chef cache folder and aptitude cache.

Comment: As far as I know, all Chef resources can specify path to local file system - so downloading packages doesn't have to be from network. If you are asking also about cookbooks, you can download them and show local path for them in Vagrant. Copying cache sometimes won't work.

Comment: this would require me to go through every cookbook and every gem to track down every lib they use... with 100s of gems and a dozen or 2 cookbooks this seems a fool errand.

Comment: Yeah, but gems you can install once and they stay there forever. I don't know, what cookbooks you are actually using, but in mine there is just one main download source and it isn't so hard to make them offline. Copying cache would do this, but sometimes - for me - it refused to get resources from this folder and tried to download them one more time. I really do not know why, though.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, which demonstrates the irony inherent to environments like Chef -- Chef is a dependency management tool that has zero concept of managing its own dependencies.  The problem is exacerbated by the lack of foresight and discipline in the Ruby community.

Comment: i spent about 2 weeks on this (partly because this was my first experience working with ruby) ill outline my experience in an answer.